# How to store sql resultset fields in to a separate array variable using java?

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, resultset

I have three fields of a table orderinfo ,having around 2500 rows in my database.

Now I want to store each and every field data in a array variable.

when i run the code, I am getting Null values stored on the array variable.

Below I have provided my code.

Can any one help me to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
package com;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException;



public class getOrderinfo {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.14/opsbank-ii";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "p@ssw0rd";
    public static int row_count = 0;
    public static int count_for_totalfiles = 0;
    public static String filename_allocated = "";
    public static String dateofcar_allocated = "";
    public String row_data = "";
    public static int orderid = 0;
    public static int[] orderid_sto = new int[5000];
    public static String flow = "";
    public static String[] flow_sto = new String[5000];
    public static Date dateofprocessing;
    public static Date[] dateofprocessing_sto = new Date[5000];

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //public static void main(String[] args) 
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the Date(Format : 2016-02-22) ");
            String date = scanner.next();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date date2 = null;
            /* try {
             //Parsing the String
             date2 = (Date) dateFormat.parse(date);
             } 
             catch (ParseException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
             }*/
            System.out.println("Input Date:" + date2);

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;

            sql = "select orderid,flow,dateofprocessing from orderinfo where ordertype ='CAR' and dateofprocessing like '%" + date + "%'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                int i = 0;

                orderid = rs.getInt("orderid");
                System.out.println("Order ID get : " + orderid);
                orderid_sto[i++] = orderid;
                flow = rs.getString("flow");
                flow_sto[i++] = flow;
                dateofprocessing = rs.getDate("dateofprocessing");
                dateofprocessing_sto[i++] = dateofprocessing;

                System.out.println("orderid :" + orderid + " || Flow : " + flow + " || date :  " + dateofprocessing);

                i++;
                row_count++;
                count_for_totalfiles++;
                //Display values
                //System.out.print("BOOKISSID: " + BOOKISSID);
                //System.out.print(", ISSN: " + ISSN);
                //System.out.println("\n");

            }
            System.out.println("Total Number of CAR orders found for the date : " + date2 + " = " + row_count);
            System.out.println("The Details after calculation:\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < count_for_totalfiles; j++) {
                System.out.println("I am executed number : " + j);
                System.out.println("orderid :" + orderid_sto[j] + " || Flow : " + flow_sto[j] + " || date: " + dateofprocessing_sto[j]);

            }
            // row_count=0; 
            //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (MySQLSyntaxErrorException mysqlerr) {
            System.out.println("date issue");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }// nothing we can do
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
    }//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

Kindly help any one if possible.[image: screen shot for db]

Comment: You should really consider creating and populating an object, and adding that object to a list (or array), instead of having separate arrays for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increment `i` once time like this:

```
    orderid_sto[i]=rs.getInt("orderid");
   flow_sto[i]=rs.getString("flow");
   dateofprocessing_sto[i]=rs.getDate("dateofprocessing");
   i++;
```

And remove these line because they are present in finally block:

```
   //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
   stmt.close();
   conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only increment i once, you are incrmenting it multiple times

your code:

```
orderid_sto[i++]=orderid;
flow=rs.getString("flow");
flow_sto[i++]=flow;
dateofprocessing=rs.getDate("dateofprocessing");
dateofprocessing_sto[i++]=dateofprocessing;

i++;
```

Comment: @ ashish .Thank you sir.the earlier code works fine.